# Upsert in Firebase Firestore without the onFailure callback

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There must be a better way to make upsert in Firebase Firestore in Kotlin.

I have collection of users that contains another collection userDocuments that contains field called highlights containing list of highlights.

I cannot use set and merge options as that will override the highlights list.

Any ideas how to make the code better. I do not like making two database requests on create and handling the failure like this. Maybe my database structure can be also optimized but I thought it is smart as all private userData will be stored in users collections with some subcollections.

My database structure is like this:
users -> {userId} -> userDocuments -> {docId} -> highlights ["this will be highlighted"]

users, and userDocuments are collections. Highlights is a field on userDocument.

docId might not yet be there, there will be 1000 of documents. And I do not want to add it to every user. I want it to be there, only when they make a change such as add or remove highlight to list of highlights.

```
  usersCollection
                .document(userId)
                .collection("userDocuments")
                .document(docId)
                .update("highlights", FieldValue.arrayUnion(text))
                .addOnFailureListener { err ->
                    // TODO should be handled differently
                    if (err is FirebaseFirestoreException &&
                        err.code === FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.NOT_FOUND
                    ) {
                        val highlights = listOf(text)
                        usersCollection
                            .document(it)
                            .collection("userDocuments")
                            .document(docId)
                            .set(mapOf("highlights" to highlights), SetOptions.merge())
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Upsert on firebase you can use transactions too, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#kotlin+ktx basically kinda upsert, but usually retrieve the document and push it is kinda a document database works

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact fields you want to update.

Answer (score 2):

You can update using dictionary notation or dot notation too.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

```
db.collection("userDocuments")
  .document(docId)
  .update({
    "highlights": FieldValue.arrayUnion(text)
  });
```

You can consider using transactions as I mentioned in the comment above. But not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That should still trigger FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.NOT_FOUND as the userCollection is not present at that time.  I ll have a look at Firestore transactions and try to come up with better that might be a way to go. 

Indeed it did: 
Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=No document to update: projects/XXXXProject/databases/(default)/documents/users/xXXXXXnL83/userDocuments/9vXXXXXu2r, cause=null}.

Comment: I got you, so the better way to modify a stream record should be a transaction, is the way to emulate a transactional db with firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#kotlin+ktx

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I have read the documentation. I can write the transaction to read the userDocument and after call update or create. 

But this will be always 2 operations rather than update or update and set.  The biggest issue I have with using transactions is that I want to support offline mode too.

I can possibly be a bit smarter around this as I have listener on userDocuments so I should have up to date data and be able to decide based on that.